# mutable copy copies by reference, not value?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

Apparently mutableCopy copies by reference, not value. Ie if I do this:

```
NSMutableArray arrayA = [arrayB mutableCopy];
```

then change values of arrayB, then arrayA's values will also be changed.

I think Java has a clone() method to copy by value.. is there an equivalent in objective c?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `mutableCopy` method performs “shallow” copy.  Each element of `arrayA` is a reference to an object that is also in `arrayB`.  If you add elements to `arrayA` (or remove elements), `arrayB` will be unchanged, and vice versa.  But since the elements of `arrayA` and `arrayB` reference the same objects, a change to one of those objects “shows up” in both arrays.

If you want a one-level deep copy of `arrayB`, you can do this:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayA = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:arrayB copyItems:YES];
```

That will have this effect:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayA = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (id element in arrayB) {
    [arrayA addObject:[element copy]]; //copies immutable objects to new array  
}
```

Comment: Yup I tried that but unfortunately it creates an exceptioN: -[MyObject copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x861f820. I suspect that MyObjects need to implement some protocol to be able to clone (copyWithZone)?

Comment: You need to implement `NSCopying`: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: got it, looks like Java's Clone.

Comment: What if we need mutableCopy of elements in new array ? Is there any method ?

Answer (score 0):

To deep copy an array you need to use:

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: oldArray copyItems:YES];
```

This performs a `copyWithZone:` on each object in the array

Answer (score -1):

The regular `[NSMutableArray copy]` method will, as per Apple's documentation, return a "functionally independent object with values identical to the original at the time the copy was made." You should probably just use that.

To be totally sure that it is mutable, use `[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[otherArray copy]]`.

Comment: This is not what is being asked. To make a mutable copy you should use `-mutableCopy`. Have a look at `NSMutableCopying`: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSMutableCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html